# c++: does static_cast<int> std::sqrt(x) always give exact result for positive integers that are squares?

Tags: c++, sqrt

is it guaranteed, that `static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(x * x)) == x` for all positive x for which x*x does not overflow?

If not, how would I compute the square root of such numbers robustly?

Comment: You'll need to make sure that `x*x` is a value that can be exactly represented as `double`.  This would be true on a system with IEEE 754 `double`s if `x*x` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

From cppreference:

> `std::sqrt` is required by the IEEE standard to be exact. The only other operations required to be exact are the arithmetic operators and the function `std::fma`. After rounding to the return type (using default rounding mode), the result of `std::sqrt` is indistinguishable from the infinitely precise result. In other words, the error is less than 0.5 ulp. Other functions, including `std::pow`, are not so constrained. ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt))

So I can't see any reason to worry, given your constraints.